# Dispatch clear all my data form input reactjs

Tags: reactjs, dispatch

I use reactjs. But when I handle onClick event. After I clicked on Button and dispatch an event. It's clear all my data in Input. I don't know why the data is cleared and how can prevent it.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Input, Form, Checkbox, Button, Row, Col, notification } from "antd";
import { loginRequest } from "../../../store/userStore";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
export default function SignInPage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    dispatch(loginRequest());
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Input>
      </Input>
      <Input>
      </Input>
      <Button onClick={() => {
        handleSubmit()
      }}>Click</Button>

    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are these inputs and button rendered within a form element by any chance? Can you provide a more comprehensive code example?

Comment: That's all my code. I also use react-saga as a middleware. @DrewReese

Comment: Are these `Form, Checkbox, Button, Row, Col, notification` just extraneous imports then? Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we can examine and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

I'm guessing these inputs and button are being rendered with a `form` element and you aren't preventing the default form action from occurring. Button elements have a `type="submit"` by default, so when clicked will invoke the default form action and reload the page (clearing the inputs).

## Solution

Call `preventDefault` on the event object.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent the default
  dispatch(loginRequest());
}
```

Comment: I tried it. But it can't solve my problem. Input still cleaned when I clicked on button. I think the problem is because dispatch action. But I don't know how.